# using button image similar to Apple's app icons

Tags: ios, image, button, appstore-approval

My app offers an option of sending text messages. It does that by taking user to the Messages App when the user clicks a button. This button is similar to the Messages Icon. It is composed of a cloud with a pointy arrow. Instead of green background, it uses blue. My question is, since the functionality of this button is to take user to the Messages App, am I allowed to use similar icon as Apple did? Should I expect trouble when the app goes to review? Do you have any experience with situations similar to mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use Apple app icons, images, or screenshots in your designs.** Apple designs are copyrighted and can’t appear in your UI unless they are provided by the system.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Iconography.html).

Comment: Thank you! The part you address in Update was confusing to me. I guess it is better to walk on safe side

Comment: Yep I removed it, use own icons much better.